# How to show the value from the database into the form with manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have django model:

```
class foroccasion(models.Model):
        occasions=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.occasions

class forstyle(models.Model):
        style=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.style

class forbodytype(models.Model):
        bodytype=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.bodytype

class  Input(models.Model):
    apparelid=models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    userid=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    occassion=models.ManyToManyField(foroccasion)
    bodytype=models.ManyToManyField(forbodytype)
    style=models.ManyToManyField(forstyle)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.userid
```

and forms.py as:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model=Input
    exclude=('userid',)
```

i have inserted some values into the database throung form.save() now , i have to update my previous database by new values inserted by the user. like i want to show my form with previously filled values as i am new to django so i am unable to connect this manytomany thing in the form so help me in showing the form with previous value how to do it?

Comment: You are looking for [`instance` of a `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: yes i was looking for that bt the selected value in the multiple choice form was not coming